# Mark outlier in parallel coordinate plot using ggparcoord

Tags: r, plot, charts, ggplot2, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to highlight an outlier data point in a parallel coordinate plot. This is how my dataframe looks:

Using this code below,

```
library(devtools)
install_version("MMST", version = "0.6-1.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
MMST.out(dest.folder = '.',datasets='bodyfat')
ggparcoord(data = bodyfat, alphaLines = 0.2)
```

this is how my plot looks currently:
[image: ParCoord Plot]

I want to mark one of the outlier lines (seen in the plot above) with a different color. How do I achieve that using ggplot2?

Comment: You forgot the input data

Comment: exclude the outlier from the data in `ggparcoord` and plot them separatly..

Comment: ^Yeah, that worked, thanks. I was earlier trying to plot the outlier using ggparcoord again, but then discovered that it could be done using a basic geom_line()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, I extracted the outliers from the data in ggparcoord and plotted them separately. Here's the new code now:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("MMST", version = "0.6-1.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
MMST.out(dest.folder = '.',datasets='bodyfat')
a=ggparcoord(data = bodyfat, alphaLines = 0.2)
out1=which.max(a$data[a$data$variable=='hip',]$value)
out2=which.max(a$data[a$data$variable=='ankle',]$value)
df1=a$data[a$data$.ID==out1,]
df2=a$data[a$data$.ID==out2,]
a + geom_line(data = df1 ,aes(y=value), color='red', alpha=0.5) +
geom_line(data = df2 ,aes(y=value), color='blue', alpha=0.5)
```

And this is how the output looks:

[PCP with highlighted outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfAm8.jpg)

Thanks for the help.